# using Image Magick converted files as background for PDF's created with PDF :: API2

Tags: perl, pdf, background, imagemagick, converters

i converted a pdf to an image using image magick and perl.
using this function:

```
sub PDFtoIMAGE
  {
         foreach my $a (keys %dir) #just using I/O::dir to get full list of files
         {
          my $file = $a;
          printf "$file\n";

             if($file=~/\.pdf/ || $file=~/\.PDF/)
               {
                 my $Img = Image::Magick->new;
                 $Img->Set(density => '300');            
                 print "reading: $file\n";
                 $Img->read("$path$file");
                 my ($width, $height, $size, $format)=$Img->Ping("$path$file");
                 print "$width, $height, $size, $format\n";
                 $Img->Extent(width=>$width,height=>$height);
                 $file=~s/\.pdf/\.jpg/;
                 $file=~s/\.PDF/\.jpg/;
                 print "creating: $file\n";
                 $Img->Write("png24:$path$file");
                 print "created: $file\n";
               }
         }
   }
```

then i am trying to use the result file i get as the background image for a pdf i am trying to create using PDF::API2 but when i run my PDF::API2 script to create my PDF i get this error:
"cant call method val on an undefined value /../Image.pm line 66".
this error refers to the file i created using image magick!!

for some reason some of the images i create when converting pdfs work fine and some dont.
i already spent along time on this problem... can anyone help me?

Comment: unrelated tip: use the `/i` flag to do case insensitive matches → `$file =~ /\.pdf\z/i` and `$file =~ s/\.pdf\z/.jpg/i`. The `\z` anchores at the end of string.

Comment: thanks, i usually do. in this case i had to state them explicitly.

Comment: can you use some image viewer or editor to find differences between the image that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: @golimer i did, i tried 'gimp' but with little success. the thing is im sure that its just some possibly minor issue im overlooking.

Comment: i think this issue calls for a ghostscript specialist